# $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ - How does $D$ displace the plane?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

If $ax + by + cz = 0$ defines the orientation of a plane which passes through the origin, how is it that adding the constant $d$, the position of the plane moves?

I understand that $d$ is the distance from the origin, however it doesn't indicate which direction. Suppose you want to move the plane up by $5$. How does the result differ from wanting to move forward by $5$? In both cases, $5$ is added.

Comment: you move along the normale of the plane. :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $d$ is not the distance from the origin: $2x+3y+4z+5=0$ and $4x+6y+8z+10=0$ are the same plane.  But in both cases the point $(-\frac{5}{2},0,0)$ or equivalently $(-\frac{10}{4},0,0)$ lie on the plane.  Similarly the point $(0,-\frac{5}{3},0)$ or equivalently $(0,-\frac{10}{6},0)$, and the point $(0,0,-\frac{5}{4})$ or equivalently $(0,0,-\frac{10}{8})$, lie on the plane

Comment: So what is it the distance from?

Answer (score 2):

We can get the nice normal form like this:
$$
a x + b y + c z = d \iff \\
(a, b, c) \cdot (x,y,z) = d
$$
Now if $n = (a, b, c)$ is not zero then we can divide by the norm and get
$$
\frac{n}{\lVert n\rVert} \cdot (x,y,z) = \frac{d}{\lVert n \rVert} = D
$$
Now the right hand side $D$ is the (possibly signed) distance to the origin of the plane with unit normal vector $n/\lVert n \rVert$.

Let $u_r = r e_r$ be the vector from the origin to the closest point on the plane, where $e_r$ is a unit vector. Then we have
$$
D = \frac{n}{\lVert n\rVert} \cdot r e_r = r (\pm 1)
$$
depending on what $n$ (we have two sides) was chosen.
So $D$ ist the distance up to a sign.

Comment: Isn't the normal simply a, b, c? What does x,y,z signify?

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ are coordinates of a point within the plane. About the normal, yes, but we like a unit normal.

Comment: Why do we need the coordinates of a point within the plane? Surely knowing the normal, and the plane's distance + direction from the origin includes all the information needed to specify all possibly positions and orientations.

Comment: The plane is the solution to that equation in the sense $H = \{ (x,y,z) \mid (a, b, c) \cdot (x,y,z) = d \}$. For short we write $(a,b,c) \cdot (x,y,z) = d$ or we might even just provide $(a, b, c)$ and $d$, indeed. My answer was meant to give you the information that $d$ is the distance only in case $(a, b, c)$ is a vector with norm 1.

Comment: Does norm 1 mean it's a unit vector?

Comment: Is (x,y,z) any point on the plane, or generally the centre (so, at the origin 0,0,0, assuming the plane hasn't been moved)?

Comment: Ok, so I see that if (x,y,z) are any point on the plane, and (a,b,c) is the normal, we have enough information to conclude the positioning of the plane in 3D space. I still don't see of what importance D is.

Comment: $d$ is the (signed) distance of the plane to the origin (I called this $D$ above) multiplied with the norm of $(a, b, c)$, thus $d = D \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$. And the distance of the plane is the distance between that point of the plane, which is closest to the origin, and the origin. Note that if $n$ is a normal vector, then $-n$ is a normal vector as well.

Comment: I'm assuming that D is an absolute value?

Comment: $D$ might be negative, depending on your choice of $n$ (the plane has two sides).

Answer (score 2):

Given a plane

$$
a x + b y + c z + d = 0
$$

Assuming that $a^2+b^2+c^2 > 0$ there exist $x_0,y_0,z_0$ such that

$$
a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0) = a x + b y + c z + d = 0
$$

by choosing $x_0,y_0,z_0$ such that

$d = a x_0+b y_0+c z_0$

so the existence of $d \ne 0$ implies on an origin translation on the original plane

$$
a x+b y+c z=0
$$

to a point $p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$

The feeling of translation should be obtained by adopting a plane orientation. This orientation can be associated to the plane normal vector orientation  $\vec n = (a,b,c)$ so we can feel the translation sense by analyzing the sign of $< p_0, \vec n >$